# How do I solve this? Where did x and y come from if it started with a and b?

Tags: java

How do I solve this?

Consider the following method:

```
public int fun2( int x, int y)
{
  y -= x;
  return y;
}
```

What are the values of the variables a and b after the following code is executed?

```
int a=3, b=7;
b = fun2(a, b);
a = fun2(b, a);
```

Comment: Maybe you should do your own homework

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `y` are the names that `fun2` uses *internally* to refer to the values provided by the *external* variables `a` and `b`.

`fun2(a, b)` is evaluated first. Whatever that call returns becomes the *new* value of `b`. Because `x` and `y` have primitive types, `y -= x` does not affect the value of the variable `b` that was passed as an argument. Thus, `b = fun2(a, b)` behaves exactly the same as `b = fun2(3, 7)` would.